# How to get selected value from Dropdown list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can you get the selected value from drop down list using JavaScript? I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
var sel = document.getElementById('select1');
var sv = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
alert(sv);
```

Comment: Can you paste your html content along with the javascript function used

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Comment: Check out this : http://javascriptstutorial.com/blog/selecting-dropdown-element-using-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is working fine with me.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <select id="select1">
        <option value="1">test1</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
        <option value="3">test3</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <button onClick="GetSelectedItem('select1');">Get Selected Item</button>
</div>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
function GetSelectedItem(el)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(el);
    var strSel = "The Value is: " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value + " and text is: " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(strSel);
}
```

**See** that you are using the right id. *In case you are using it with ASP.NET, the id changes when rendered*.

Comment: Why not pass the select element into the function directly? Then you will not need to search for the select element by id.

Comment: If you are invoking the script from the same element, passing the element is easy by using 'this'. However from other elements, as in this case, the good way will be to pass the element id and get the element in the function. I just updated my answer based on this.

Answer (score 4):

Direct `value` should work just fine:

```
var sv = sel.value;
alert(sv);
```

The only reason your code might fail is when there is no item selected, then the `selectedIndex` returns -1 and the code breaks.

Comment: see i have dropdown and i select one item from it and trying to display it using alert but not working alert is empty

Comment: The code must be inside some event handler, just having it lying around won't help. Post more of your code and we'll see what you done wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Hope it's working for you

```
 function GetSelectedItem()
 {
     var index = document.getElementById(select1).selectedIndex;

     alert("value =" + document.getElementById(select1).value); // show selected value
     alert("text =" + document.getElementById(select1).options[index].text); // show selected text 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to get the selected value of dropdown in javascript

First we design the UI for dropdown

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<select class="form-control" id="language">
    <option>---SELECT---</option>
    <option>JAVA</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>C++</option>
    <option>PERL</option>
</select>
```

Next we need to write script to get the selected item

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#language').change(function () {
        var doc = document.getElementById("language");
        alert("You selected " + doc.options[doc.selectedIndex].value);
    });
});
```

Now When change the dropdown the selected item will be alert.

Answer (score 0):

I would say change var sv = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
to var sv = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

It worked for me. Directing you to where I found my solution 
[Getting the selected value dropdown jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875117/getting-the-selected-value-dropdown-jstl)

Answer (score 0):

According to Html5 specs you should use --
 *element.options[e.selectedIndex].**text***

e.g. if you have select box like below :

```
<select id="selectbox1">
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
<br/>
<button onClick="GetItemValue('selectbox1');">Get Item</button>
```

you can get value using following script :

```
<script>
 function GetItemValue(q) {
   var e = document.getElementById(q);
   var selValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text ;
   alert("Selected Value: "+selValue);
 }
</script>
```

Tried and tested.