# Getting the selected value dropdown jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

With this drop down I'll select a value and pass in a url, but with this code i'm not able to get only the selected one, can you guys help me to setup a c:if and mark selected on the side?. Thanks anyway.

```
<select>
<c:forEach var="foo" items="${bar}">
<option value="${foo}">${foo}</option>
</c:forEach></select>


<div class="links" style="font-size: 110%">
<a href="someURL?path=${foo}">someName</a>
</div>
```

Ex:

```
<select>
<c:forEach var="name" items="${names}">
<option value="${name}">${name}</option>
</c:forEach></select>
```

After i select the name, place the selected one in the url

```
<div class="links" style="font-size: 110%">
<a href="someURL?path=${name}">someName</a>
</div>
```

Sorry, my english isn't that good so it's hard sometimes to express myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<option value="${foo}" 
        <c:if test="${param.path == foo}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${foo}</option>
```

Read http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Comment: the thing is this ${bar} is a list, so when i'm putting 2 items or more i got this [something1,something2]

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're sending a request to a URL like `someURL?path=hello`. And in response to this request, you want to display a select box containing all the items from a list called `bar`, and select the item in bar which is equal to `hello`, right? If so, that's what my answer above does. If not so, please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: what i want is select a item in the drop down and put this selected item in the url so i can send as a param to another controller

Comment: Well, just submit the form containing this select box, and the selected option value will be sent as a parameter. If you really want to modify a link in the same page as the select box each time an option is selected, then the JSTL is irrelevant: you need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

u can use javascript traversal to get selected value,if u do not use this ,u can use request.setAttribute("","") to set value ,<%= request.getAttribute("","")%> to get value ,
<% for(){}%> ,javascript to get selected value.