# Can we retrieve the default selected value of dropdown bar using javascript's document.getElementById method?

Tags: javascript, html-select

I want to get the default value of the dropdown bar using javascript.

In the code below

```js
alert(document.getElementById("dropdown").selected)
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

the audi option is by default selected value of the drop-down bar. with help of `document.getElementById("drop-down").value=""` we can get the value the user has selected(say it is Saab) but I want to get the default value of that particular drop-down bar(i.e audi)

I tried using `document.getElementById("selement").selected`
 but it doesn't seem to be working

I want to get the default regardless of what the user selects. I have two tabs. the first tab has this drop down. When the user moves onto the next tab the drop-down in the first tab should display the default value (such as "select any options below" or in the case of the example , "audi") but for me the drop-down shows the one which the user had selected previously before the tab was changed. 
So is there a way where I can get the value 'audi' through JS ?

Comment: Did you try using `.value`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected value from Dropdown list in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832375/how-to-get-selected-value-from-dropdown-list-in-javascript)

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt .value returns the value which the user selects. If the user selects Saab and if I use .value it returns the 'Saab' but I want to get the value 'audi'  even if the user doesn't select that !

Comment: It returns the `selected` value.Yes if the user selects `saab` then selected attribute will be for `saab`.If you need to get the default value then get the value as soon as the `DOM` gets loaded before user changes the vallue.

Comment: @ObitoUchiha do you control the HTML? And I assume you want to get the `default` regardless of what the user selected?

Comment: @Bibberty yes, I want to get the default regardless of what the user selects. My problem is I have two tabs. the first tab has this drop down. When the user moves onto the next tab the drop-down in the first tab should display the default value (such as "select any options below" or in the case of the example , "audi") but for me the drop-down shows the one which the user had selected previously before the tab was changed.

Comment: @ObitoUchiha I added some sample code. But if you have control of the HTML. I would like to suggest different, let me add a further snippet.

Comment: @Bibberty yes I have control of the HTML and Thanks , I will be trying out your solutions . !

Comment: Please vote for answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In this example we grab the `default` at `DOMContentLoaded` and store it.

```js
let defaultValue;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  defaultValue = document.querySelector('#selement').value;
});

document.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('#selement')) {
    console.log(`Default: ${defaultValue} - Selected: ${e.target.value}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="selement">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Assuming complete control of the HTML:

Note: we add a `data` tag.

```js
document.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('#selement')) {
    let defaultValue = e.target.querySelector('option[data-default="true"]').value;
    console.log(`Default: ${defaultValue} - Selected: ${e.target.value}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="selement">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" data-default="true" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Again assuming HTML control, but a slight adaption of the `data` option.

```js
document.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('#selement')) {
    console.log(`Default: ${e.target.dataset.default} - Selected: ${e.target.value}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="selement" data-default="audi">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/babel">
              let defaultValue;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  defaultValue = document.querySelector('#selement').value;
});

document.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('#selement')) {
    console.log(`Default: ${defaultValue} - Selected: ${e.target.value}`);
  }
});

</script>`

This the code I took from you and executed in my <script> tag but it doesn't seem to be working , the console doesn't show anything !

Comment: Can you post code in Repl.it or sandbox.io ? We can look there.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `value`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("selement").value);
```

```html
<select id="selement">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if an `option` element is selected using `.select`, so you could loop through all options and get the value of the one which is selected, like that:

```
function getSelectedValue(dropDownId) {

    var options = document.getElementById(dropDownId).children;

    for (option of options) {
        if (option.selected) {
            return option.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `dropDownId` is the id of your `select` element.

But since the selected option will be changed by the user, you could store the value of the default selected option in a variable as soon as the page loads your script, with for example a simple global variable like `var defaultValue = getSelectedValue("my-drop-down");`