# How to get value of HTML dropdown menu for use in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, drop-down-menu, boolean

I'm trying to pass the answers from multiple dropdown menus like this one to a single button to answer question for a user.  Any advice is very much appreciated.

```js
<script lang="text/JavaScript">
    
        function myFunction(){
            //variables
            var firstClass = document.getElementById("class1").value;
            console.log(firstClass);

            if(firstClass == Yes) {
                firstClass = true;
            }
            
            else {
                firstClass = false;
            }

        }
            
   </script>
```

```html
<form id="collegeGrad">
        <p>Have you completed CLASS 1?</p>
        <label>First Class</label>
        <select id="class1">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
```

Currently the program says that "Yes" is not defined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get selected value from Dropdown list in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832375/how-to-get-selected-value-from-dropdown-list-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You missed the **quotes** on the first If statement.
It should have been like this ==>
`if (firstClass == 'Yes') {firstClass = true;}`